# Кастомная клавиатура iOS, UISegmentedControlStyle deprecated.

Tags: xcode, ui, objective-c, ios7

Подскажите пожалуйста насчет кастомной клавиатуры. Смотрел код здесь http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-a-simple-keyboard-with-custom-navigation-buttons но тут устарела тема с UISegmentedControlStyle
"The styles of the segmented control. (Deprecated. Use tintColor instead.)" Из документации я ничего не понял, как заменить одно на другое https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl . Может кто-то делал такую клавиатуру другим образом? И подскажите пожалуйста как заменить старый класс на новый.

Answer (score 1):

[Полная инструкция как сделать то что Вы хотите.](http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html) Впилить `UISegmentedControl` туда думаю для Вас не составит труда, равно как и его имитацию из двух `UIButton` если Вас не устроит внешний вид контрола предлагаемый iOS7